# ng-bootstrap: No provider for NgbPopover

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I've imported the NgbModule.forRoot() to app.module, imported NgbModule to the child module, added NgbPopover to the component's constructor. What am I missing?

Comment: Why did you add `NgbPopover` to the component's constructor? As the error is saying, we don't have such provider as part of ng-bootstrap so it won't work... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes I did. I want to close the popover from the controller.

Comment: If you want to close a popover from a controller you can query for it (as for any other directive) or just have a reference to it (as shown in the "Custom and manual triggers" part of our demo: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples). Hard to suggest the best solution as your question lacks details. Expand your question so people might have more input.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource, thanks. I'll just close the popup from the template.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather old question, still I stumbled across it while facing a similar problem. The question clearly lacks some details, but the error message says that there is no provider configured. I solved the problem by adding one to my component's ts file:

```
  @Component({
    selector: '[mycomponent]',
    templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.component.css'],
    providers: [
      NgbPopover
    ]
  })
```

And of course it is injected in the constructor:

```
constructor(private popover: NgbPopover) {
}
```